# How can I sync my root gedit with my user gedit's preferences?

Tags: gedit, root

When I open a file with root gedit I'd like to have the same setup as my normal gedit. So theme, preferences, and addons.

Can I set up some sym links in the right spot to achieve this?

Comment: USe `gksu` instead of plain `sudo` gksu uses *YOUR* profile but with elevated privileges.

Comment: @Uri Herrera - Not on my computers. It uses the root profile. Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 10.04LTS.

Comment: Yes... Become root: `sduo su -` and then `ln -s /home/username/.filename /root/` or `cat /home/username/.filename ~/.filename`

Comment: @Christopher, I am familiar with creating a link, but to what files/folders are needed for gedit themes, preferences, and addons?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is quite impossible because gedit manages its settings through gconf and to sync these it would require a gnome-settings-deamon running for root.

Comment: It is possible. See the answer I wrote today.

Answer (score 0):

You normally wouldn't synchronize normal gedit settings with root gedit user settings.

Root has its own settings, and the computer user has his own settings. The two are not the same. This is by design.

When you are operating as root, you are using the root user's profile, and when you're operating as yourself, you're using your personal profile. Each has its own permissions and ownership, tied to that particular account. They're not intended to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Have `sudo` inherit your user account `gedit` settings

[image: sgedit 80 column right slider.gif]

In this example the user settings for font name, font size, tab stops, convert tabs to spaces, 80 column highlight, and right side thumbnail slider bar have been inherited by `sudo`.

With regular `sudo -H gedit` you cannot make nor save these configuration settings. With the script below `sgedit` the settings are inherited from your user account.

This script also addresses the "`gksu` is bad and not installed by default" and "`pkexec` is hard to setup" problems.

---

### Background

I've been nagged by the same issue for years. This weekend's project was to write the `sgedit` script:

- Call using `sgedit filename1 filename2...`
- Gets user's gedit settings for tab stops, fonts, line-wrap, etc.
- Elevates to `sudo -H` to preserve file ownership whilst getting root powers.
- Requests password if last sudo has timed out.
- Gets sudo's gedit settings
- Compares differences between user and sudo gedit settings
- Runs `gsettings set` on the differences only (reduces 174 `set` commands to a dozen or less. Next time it's run perhaps only one or two changes but often times none.
- Calls gedit as a background task such that terminal prompt reappears immediately.

## Bash script `sgedit`

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: sgedit
# PATH: /mnt/e/bin
# DESC: Run gedit as sudo using $USER preferences
# DATE: June 17, 2018.

# Must not prefix with sudo when calling script
if [[ $(id -u) == 0 ]]; then
    zenity --error --text "You cannot call this script using sudo. Aborting."
    exit 99
fi

# Get user preferences before elevating to sudo
gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit | grep -v history | \
    grep -v docinfo | \
    grep -v virtual-root | grep -v state.window > /tmp/gedit.gsettings

sudoFunc () {

    # Must be running as sudo
    if [[ $(id -u) != 0 ]]; then
        zenity --error --text "Sudo password authentication failed. Aborting."
        exit 99
    fi

    # Get sudo's gedit preferences
    gsettings list-recursively | grep -i gedit | grep -v history | \
        grep -v docinfo | \
        grep -v virtual-root | grep -v state.window > /tmp/gedit.gsettings.root
    diff /tmp/gedit.gsettings.root /tmp/gedit.gsettings | grep '>' > /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    sed -i 's/>/gsettings set/g; s/uint32 //g' /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    chmod +x /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff
    bash -x /tmp/gedit.gsettings.diff  # Display override setting to terminal
#    nohup gedit $@ &>/dev/null &
    nohup gedit -g 1300x840+1+1220 $@ &>/dev/null &
#              Set the X geometry window size (WIDTHxHEIGHT+X+Y).

}

FUNC=$(declare -f sudoFunc)
sudo -H bash -c "$FUNC; sudoFunc $*;"

exit 0
```

### Housekeeping

Copy the bash script above to a new file called `sgedit`. I recommend placing it in your `$HOME/bin` directory, ie `/home/YOURNAME/bin`. You may have to create the directory first.

Mark the file as executable using:

```
chmod a+x ~/sgedit
```

Note `~` is a shortcut for `/home/YOURNAME`.