# How can I prevent line wrapping and instead allow horizontal scrolling in Gedit?

Tags: gedit, scrolling

I am writing long lines of data to a text file using Python. But when I open the text file using **gedit**, I don't find that the lines that I wrote are displayed into one line each (i.e every line from the data that I wrote is divided into one or more lines in the file as shown in the photo).

[image: screenshot with line wrap]

What I want is to be able to scroll horizontally with gedit so that the lines that I write will be displayed in one line each.
Is it possible to scroll horizontally in gedit?

Comment: Try holding Shift and scrolling. That's how horizontal scrolling works in most modern apps

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy The scroll bar doesn't appear until you turn off Text Wrapping. Please see my answer below. Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the window bottom of `gedit` click on the Line number / Column number section:

[image: gedit text wrapping.png]

Uncheck the `Text wrapping` option and a horizontal scroll box will then appear. Lines will no longer be wrapped.

---

If you want the setting to be permanent change your preferences. Use: `Edit` => `Preverences` => `View` => `Enable text wrapping`:

[image: gedit preferences menu.png]

---

You can't access preferences if you are using `sudo -H gedit` though. You need to do this with regular user using `gedit` only. Then you can have `sudo` inherit your user preferences with a script such as this: [How can I sync my root gedit with my user gedit's preferences?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92655/how-can-i-sync-my-root-gedit-with-my-user-gedits-preferences/1047405#1047405)